# Why changes the loading time of my websites?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, caching, pagespeed

My websites are sometimes slow and sometimes fast. I have no idea why

The websites:
http://pangea.co.hu/
http://tlumaczpangea.pl/

Suddenly both of the websites got really slow, it took 20-30 sec to load. I updated the Wordpress itself and the plugins and installed/configured W3 Total Cache.

Now it loads in 1-3 seconds sometimes, but sometimes it takes much longer. In these problematic cases the browser says that it is waiting for the server.

Comment: WP has a database under the covers, correct?  Which database?  What queries are run when loading a page?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is taking time to establish the connection. You should contact your server provider. Additionally, you can try query optimizer to check where and what takes more time to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried refreshing your page a bunch of time from different browsers, but it never loaded for more than a few seconds. That sounds like a server-side issue that you should contact your provider about, with specific timestamps on when it happened. I see no obvious reason for it to happen from the code alone.

But nonetheless, a few optimization ideas: you should really compress the background image with a tool like [tinypng.com](https://tinypng.com/), you save over 1 Mb from that one picture alone.

Another big resource-hug are the multiple google fonts: do you REALLY need the full versions of Open Sans, Roboto, Raleway AND Courgette for this site? Try including only the fonts you use, and only with their desired fontweights.

For further ideas, keep an eye on [Google's PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), or [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).